# Hitting tab in Zsh eats above lines

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just made the switch to Zsh, but I'm facing a weird problem with it: every time I hit the tab key, the prompt goes up a line, thus eating what was above.

In order to demonstrate the problem more clearly, I created a GIF:

[image]

I'm using a custom theme and Oh My Zsh. You can find the theme here: http://pastebin.com/12dZtZf3.

**EDIT:** The problem seems to reside in my theme, as using other themes solves the problem.

**EDIT:** The culprit seems to be in the function that prints the row of dashes and the date above the prompt:

```
_professional_prompt_header() {
  echo -n "$bg[grey]"

  for i in {0..$(( $(tput cols) / 2 - 6 ))}; do
    echo -n "--"
  done

  # Uncommenting this line fixes the problem.
  # Tried echo without -n and print, but no success.
  echo -n " %*$reset_color"      
}
```

Comment: Something in your tab completion is generating an escape sequence that is somehow causing the terminal to redraw the screen while deleting the 3rd(?) line above the current cursor position. I can't begin to imagine a typo that would have that effect, but I'd say your tab completion setup is the place to start.

Comment: @chepner I'm relying in Oh My Zsh plugins for all behaviour: I have the following plugins activated: `plugins=(git nvm colorize cp colored-man sublime extract z)`. Weirdly enough, changing my theme fixes the problem.

Comment: Likely something in your prompt is screwing up the display of the terminal. Set your prompt to something trivial and retry. I bet everything will work as expected.

Comment: It is very likely that you have put somewhere an escape codes without `%{...%}` brackets, probably in colors definition. So instead e.g. `PS1=$'\e[31mBeautiful prompt>\e[0m'` you should have `PS1=$'%{\e[31m%}Beautiful prompt>%{\e[0m%}'`

Answer (score 4):

This has also emerged as an issue with multiline prompts in the release of zsh 5.3. As of 2017-01-13, a patch has not been released. A discussion and explanation can be found in [this prezto issue](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/1245).

More discussion of the offending zsh issue itself can be [found here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2017/msg00021.html).

Hopefully a fix will emerge from the zsh project. If not, some workarounds mentioned on that github repo are to make your `PROMPT` variable only a single line, outputting any other lines in the `precmd` function. This seems like a pain, however, so until it is fixed (or decided to be a "feature"), the easiest fix sounds like it is to roll back to zsh 5.2.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/1245#issuecomment-282607956) from February 27, this will be solved in the (as of May 10 2017 yet to be released) version 5.3.2. According to the above cited comment, the fix is already available on the [zsh git mirror](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh)

Comment: Still experiencing a variation of issue with zsh 5.4.2, as of Nov 19 2017

Comment: @Marco I also was. In my case, the problem seems to happen exactly when the first line of the prompt (my prompt is 2-line) fully fills the width of the terminal; I modified my prompt to compress the cwd to reach one *less* than the end of the line, and it stopped eating lines.